# Ways to tweak my Ping in Counter-Strike

Tags: counter-strike

Are there any ways to reduce my ping in Counter-Strike 1.6?

On most servers in my country the ping is around 90-120. I like to reduce it without switching ISPs and don't want to pay for fastpath.

I don't want to get it down to around 15, but 40-60 would be a nice improvement!

Comment: see also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/676/how-can-i-reduce-latency-while-playing-world-of-warcraft/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ping is a function of your internet speed, and distance to the server.  Network geographically close servers will have lower pings than those far away.

Without a faster internet connection or a closer server your stuck where you are at.

If your computer is connected to the internet via a wireless network then that could be a bottleneck in your speed.  The fastest connection will be with a wired connection.

**Edit:** One more note; If you host the game you will have the lowest ping.

Comment: no chance to tweak the game connection and reduce lags by changing cs-config files?

Comment: No, the network is the factor in latency, and your config file cannot change network speed.

Comment: some provider's offer the option to turn error correction off which improves the ping

Comment: @F.S. - There is nothing you can do locally that gets rid of latency ( i.e. lag ).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tracert` to check for bottlenecks in your connections.

Fire up the terminal and issue the following:

```
tracert zombo.com
```

Your target doesn't really matter here, because we are focusing on the first hops. Assuming a typical home connection, with router and a DSL link:

- The first hops up and until your router (usually `192.168.1.1` or `192.168.0.1`) must not go above "1 ms", if they don't your own home setup is adding considerable latency. Linux's version of the command, `tracepath`, estimates 1.012ms latency over my short wireless link and 0.765ms over my ethernet cable.
- The following few hops after your router are your ISP's; those must be as low as possible. Values of 10ms or 20ms are okay, but definitely do complain if your ping right after the router is 50ms or more.

If you have a DSL link, you also will want to check your signal to noise ratio and attenuation ratio from your router firmware; you will want to learn more about interweaved vs fast DSL mode and other networking issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may get better ping by simply rebooting your modem/router.

Answer (score -3):

`set sv_allowupload 0` 
`sv_allowdownload 1` 
`sv_download_ingame 0`

i downloaded a config for having a better ping. this is some of it's commands. it was useful. my ping was 80. after using this config 50.

Comment: An explanation would be useful? Although I doubt this is a suitable answer for the question.

Answer (score -4):

Small suggestion to optimize ping:

1. Close all the applications that uses Internet like downloaders, torrent applications, etc.
2. Scan your system for Malware and Viruses. You can use Malware bytes Anti-Malware and your regular Antivirus program for that.
3. Clean the Junk/temporary files in your system. Use CCleaner for it. It is free and good.
4. Use ping optimizer and TCP optimizer applications.They will optimize your Internet connection.

Restart your system, then check the ping now.

Comment: Nothing you suggested would get rid of latency ( i.e. Lag )