# CS 1.6 - I'm lagging but my ping is 50

Tags: counter-strike

I always play CS 1.6 online. My ping is around 50, but I have a lot of lag. For example, I see players 3 seconds late.

In my country, the Internet is a little slow. It's 2 mbps for download and 500 kbps for upload.

Comment: This is not the game's fault. It's your pc

Comment: In one of your [answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/141762/49182), you wrote that you downloaded a file to help with your ping. I suspect that this somehow just messed up your settings. It could also be, that your internet is just to slow. You could make a [speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net/) and post the results.

Comment: Make sure to downvote without reporting back about attempted solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following settings in console:

- cl_cmdrate 60
- cl_updaterate 60
- rate 25000
- net_graph 3

Then look at the graph that pops up. What is your FPS around, and are you getting any choke or loss issues?

Comment: My fps is 300. But i limited it to 100 fps

Comment: It's limited to 100 as a requirement unless you use developer 1. If you're not seeing choke or loss issues and you still have the problems after changing to the above rates, I don't know what the solution would be.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in console !

```
cl_updaterate 10
cl_cmdrate 10
cl_showfps 1
cl_rate 9999
rate 3500000
net_graph 3
fps_max 101
fps_modem 0
```

Comment: You need to explain how it works and not just put some command

Answer (score -1):

for lagg in any cs 1.6 server. firstly c your graph.`net_graph 3` 
then as you can see the the graph with `fps ms and in and out` type `fps_max 101` 
if you see that your graph is showing fps to 100 then you are able with 101 fps . 
else you set the fps to the fps as its shown in the graph. then type `cl_cmdrate 101` if your fps supports 101, else go for `cl_cmdrate 60` and lastly you type `cl_updaterate 101` now the main part is if you see your ms from graph . if its high try to lower the `cl_updaterate 30` or `cl_updaterate 60`now you can see a lower ms but lowering the ms will make a problem with realtime bullet registry you will find that your shooting time is not perfect or your bullet regi is goin sad , now if you have a graphics card it will definitly sole your fps problem ,coz only a GPU enabled system can give 100 fps. goto your graphics card control panel and disable `vsync` `tripple buffering` and for using a steam if its updated goto your ingame console and type `gl_vsync 0` it will solve your lagg problem.else if its still sad contact ISP